# Adding set of images into a Qt project

Tags: qt

How can I add set of images from my computer to Qt project file so that I can start coding on it

Comment: Is this a programming question ?

Comment: yes it is a programming question. I want to add an image and set the conditions on that image. The images should change according to my code. In order to implement the code I should insert the images into Resources of my project. But I want to include bulk of images at a time. This is what I want to do. If you know anything please help me ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add all the files in the Qt project you can place those in the same directory and use Qt Creator to add all those images to the resource file with multiple selection. Or you can simply modify the resource file manually, since it is a simple XML like this:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file alias="...">...</file>
        <file alias="...">...</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Consider that everything you place in here is loaded into memory when the program starts. Adding too many images here might not be a good idea. Loading from the filesystem when needed could be better.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is , pressing Ctrl button on your keyboard to select more.